# Pass instance variable to a view in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In the controller I tryied to make the following:

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    super
    @test = "hello"
  end

end
```

And obviously in the `new.html.erb` I have `<%= @test %>` but nothing appers! the hello string isn't shown.

If I do so

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    @test = "hello"
    super
  end

end
```

Then the string is shown...how is that? why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  module Vehicular
    def move_forward(n)
      @position += n
    end
  end

  class Vehicle
    include Vehicular  # Adds Vehicular to the lookup path
  end

  class Car < Vehicle
    def move_forward(n)
      puts "Vrooom!"
      super            # Calls Vehicular#move_forward
    end
  end
```

Called with no arguments and no empty argument list, super calls the appropriate method with the same arguments, and the same code block, as those used to call the current method.

**EDIT:
In your example there is a respond_with in the registrations_controller#new method and thats why the  @test = "hello" is not executed.**

Comment: It is not pretty clear to me...So if it was `super(10); puts 'vrooom!'` would `'vroom!'` be shown?

Comment: I am there but it says the room has been frozen

Comment: come here...http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11809/room-for-beck03076-and-pavan-katepalli

Answer (score 2):

Based on Devise source code a block should be passed into super(). This is a kind of quick and dirty solution.

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    super do |resource|
      @test = "hello"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

A kind of elegant solution might be creating a before_action filter, just for :new method. And setting there a @test instance variable.

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :set_test, only: [:new]

  def new
    super
  end

  private

  def set_test
    @test = "hello"
  end

end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.